# ASP MVC 4, pass data from javascript (View) to a C# static method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, client-side, server-side

I'm working on a video application and I want to trace the users' actions using the video player API (Flowplayer).
I'm doing it by setting an event listener on each event to handle the "play, pause, resume, etc." events using javascript. After catching the event,I'm calling a static method placed in the server side in order to write the action to the database (and hide the tracing info from the user).

This is what I got for now:

**JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// bind listeners to all players on the page
flowplayer(function (api, root) {
    api.bind("pause", function () {
        console.info("pause", api.paused);

        var timePassed = api.video.time;
        @{
            Reporter.ReportPause(timePassed);
        }
        //... more code  ...

</script>
```

**C# Code:**

```
public static void ReportPause ( string timePassed)
{
    // do something with timePassed
}
```

I got an exception: "Cannot resolve symbol 'timePassed'".

How can I do it the right/elegant way (with minimal overhead).

Thank you all,
YNWA

Comment: no, just no. You need to read into how the razor engine works. C# code is parsed at compile time (compile of razor page, not compile of project). You cannot use javascript within it, javascript is executed at page runtime (client side)

Comment: You can't set the value of server side variable from javascript at client side.

Comment: Make an ajax call to call your server side function.

Comment: I tried Ajax but didn't know what to put in Url part since the class and method are static.

Comment: make a function in controller and call that class library function over there. and call the controller function from ajax.

Comment: try below code and make as answer if it works for you :-)

Comment: Hi Jitendra, I guess it is possible to set the value of a server side variable from javascript at client side if you using something like SignalR. Not particularly relevant for this discussion I know, but I thought probably worth mentioning.

Comment: @AlexWhite: Yes, you are right, we can do this using SignalR, but that actually make an ajax request internally to update server side variable. Purely its not possible. – Jitendra Pancholi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // bind listeners to all players on the page
        flowplayer(function (api, root) {
            api.bind("pause", function () {
                console.info("pause", api.paused);

                var timePassed = $.flowplayer().getTime();
                    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ReportPause',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { timePassed: timePassed },
        error: function (a, b, c) { onError(a, b, c, parameters); },
        success: function (data) { onSuccess(data, parameters); }
    });
                });
            }
    </script>


// Controller
public class HomeController{
    public JsonResult ReportPause(string timePassed)
    {
         TimePassedClass.ReportPause(timePassed);
         // more code
    }
}
public static class TimePassedClass
{
      public static void ReportPause(string timePassed)
       {
          // your logic
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
(You should return a JsonResult object)

Comment: make some effort from yourself :P